# Angular / Ionic carregar arquivo sempre que página iniciar

Tags: angular, ionic

Entendo que tenha algumas páginas sobre lifecycle do Angular, mas não achei como fazer chamada a uma função sempre que a página acabar de carregar.
Eu tenho uma key que ao iniciar o APP ela é definida na storage

```
this.storage.set('X-Access-Token', 'f27bf5399b81c701bd9d6158ca67bb58');
```

Quando inicio algumas páginas é necessário pegar esta Key da storage e chamada a API para carregar os dados. Fazer a chamada ao storage e API está tudo OK.

```
export class MyChannelPage implements OnInit {
      XAccessToken: any;

     constructor(
       private httpClient: HttpClient,
       private storage: Storage,
     ){}

      ngOnInit() {
           this.GetXAccessToken();
           this.ConsoleToLog();
      }

      GetXAccessToken() {
          this.storage.get('X-Access-Token').then((token) => {
          this.XAccessToken = token;
         });
      }

      ConsoleToLog(){
        console.log(this.XAccessToken);
      }
}
```

Problema é que se eu chamar a função para carregar os dados dentro do ngOnInit(), ela me retorna Undefined para a variável XAccessToken.

Acredito que deva ser algum lifecycle que preciso usar ao invês do ngOnInit();

Criei um botão para chamar a função e quando utilizo o botão as funções funcionam.

Sabem qual lifecycle preciso usar para que sempre que a página for carregada os dados serão atualizados?

Comment: Mas já tentou algum lifecycle?

Comment: @LeAndrade tentei ainda pouco com ngOnInit(), ngAfterViewChecked() e ngAfterContentView() mas não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Após ler o documento da página do Ionic (https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) vi este detalhe sobre o ngOnInit -> só será acionado toda vez que a página for criada recentemente, mas não quando voltar para a página.

Então passei a utilizar ionViewWillEnter e ionViewDidEnter